# What does "Warning: Method X is obsolete: 'deprecated'" mean?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

The speech is working fine on my real device.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Speech.Tts;

namespace App7
{
    [Activity(Label = "App7", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity, TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener
    {
        public TextToSpeech SpeechText
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


            // create text to speech object to use synthesize and speak functions.
            // first parameter: context
            // second parameter: object implemeting TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener
            this.SpeechText = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

            Button testButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            testButton.Click += delegate
            {
                this.SpeechText.Speak("Hello World, You shall not pass", QueueMode.Flush, null);
            };
            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
        }

        public void OnInit(OperationResult status)
        {
            // here you can setup language settings

            if (status.Equals(OperationResult.Success))
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Text To Speech Succeed!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            else
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Text To Speech Fail", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

The warning is on this line:

```
this.SpeechText.Speak("Hello World, You shall not pass", QueueMode.Flush, null);
```

Under this line there is a green line and the warning message is:

> Warning    1   'Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech.Speak(string, Android.Speech.Tts.QueueMode, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary)' is obsolete: 'deprecated'

Tried to google didn't find anything.
I can ignore it but I would like to know what does it mean ? And how can I fix it ?

Comment: _"Tried to google didn't find anything."_ - [Guess you missed this](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=SendKeys.SendWait&oq=SendKeys.SendWait&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1263j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech.Speak+is+obsolete), first result at time of writing

Answer (score 0):

It means [this overload](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech.Speak%28System.String,Android.Speech.Tts.QueueMode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.String%7D%29/) is deprecated in Xamarin (because Google marked it as [deprecated as of API level 21](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#speak%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.util.HashMap%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29)).

Use the other two overloads ([1](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech.Speak%28Java.Lang.ICharSequence,Android.Speech.Tts.QueueMode,Android.OS.Bundle,System.String%29/), [2](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech.Speak%28System.String,Android.Speech.Tts.QueueMode,Android.OS.Bundle,System.String%29/)) that aren't deprecated if the warning bothers you and your target API level allows it, or just ignore the warning.

Comment: Warnings should be treated like errors in any production level code

Comment: @BenKnoble Only when all code involved in the warning is under your control. Sometimes this is not the case. Here e.g. the non-deprecated method is only available on API level 21 and up. You cannot use it if you target devices below level 21.

Comment: Fair enough. As with any rule, there are exceptions.